# Installing packages in R under Linux no longer works due to bad interpreter error

Tags: r, r-package

I am running R 4.2.2 on Arch Linux. This is being run within Crostini, the Linux environment on ChromeOS (I changed the distribution from Debian to Arch as per the Arch wiki).

While running Linux within Crostini is perhaps not all that common, I haven't had any issues to date in running R and R Studio. But just in the last day, I get a "bad interpreter: Permission denied" error error when I try to install any packages from within R. Here's an example with the polyclip package.

```
install.packages("polyclip")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/polyclip_1.10-4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 80061 bytes (78 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 78 KB

* installing *source* package ‘polyclip’ ...
** package ‘polyclip’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
sh: ./configure: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘polyclip’
* removing ‘/usr/lib/R/library/polyclip’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘polyclip’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp86SWZN/downloaded_packages’
```

The existing packages I have installed work fine, and R itself appears to work as well. I just can't install any new packages.

**Update** I've discovered one issue is that I can't execute even toy scripts in /tmp -- perhaps this is a [Crostini problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/xz6nnv/why_cant_i_execute_files_in_tmp_even_when_exec_is/). Is there some way to default R installing packages into a different temp directory?

Comment: Is `sh` working? Try running `/bin/sh` from the command prompt and new prompt should execute.

Comment: Yes, from the terminal /bin/sh works. But the error appears from within R, not the terminal.

Comment: Maybe a clue - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/243051/367012

Comment: Odd to see that error there ... does `file.info("/bin/sh")` return a `mode` of something other than `"755"`? What about the values for `uid`/`gid`? (those are both `0` on my system)

Comment: @r2evans It is 755. uid and gid are both 0.

Comment: @M.Viking I tried the tmp mounting trick but no improvement.